# Spring Boot role validation controller using aspect

Tags: spring-boot, aop

I have several controller functions separated by role, and instead of doing role validation in each controller method, I found that it seems to be able to get done by using Aspect, however something isn't right in my implementation as the code in Aspect never runs

Annotation:

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ForMerchantOnly {}
```

Aspect:

```java
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class ForMerchantOnlyAspect {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ForMerchantOnlyAspect.class);

    @Before("@annotation(com.example.api.annotation.ForMerchantOnly) && args(request)")
    public void before(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceException {
        if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("request should be HttpServletRequesttype");
        }

        String domain = request.getServerName();
        System.out.println("Aspect showing domain " + domain);
        // -- other code
    }
}
```

Controller

```java
@ForMerchantOnly
@GetMapping("/list")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResp> list() {
    System.out.println("Show something");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body();
}
```

I'm assuming when i call controller /list method via chrome browser, it would hit the code in `ForMerchantOnlyAspect` but it just went into the controller method directly. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aspect was not working as it could not find a matching joinpoint . There are no controller methods that has annotation `@ForMerchantOnly` and has an argument of type `HttpServletRequest`

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) :

> args: Limits matching to join points (the execution of methods when
>   using Spring AOP) where the arguments are instances of the given
>   types.

Following aspect may be used for the requirement . Scoping designator `within` will set the scope to advice.

```java
@Before("@annotation(com.example.api.annotation.ForMerchantOnly) && within(com.example.api..*)")
  public void before() {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();

        System.out.println("Aspect showing domain " + request.getServerName());
    }
```

Also note that an Aspect is better annotated with `@Component` and `@Configuration` be used for configurations.

You may also have a look at [Method Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc-method) of Spring security framework , which lets to secure a method with annotations.

From the documentation

> From version 2.0 onwards Spring Security has improved support
>   substantially for adding security to your service layer methods. It
>   provides support for JSR-250 annotation security as well as the
>   framework’s original @Secured annotation. From 3.0 you can also make
>   use of new expression-based annotations. You can apply security to a
>   single bean, using the intercept-methods element to decorate the bean
>   declaration, or you can secure multiple beans across the entire
>   service layer using the AspectJ style pointcuts.

Comment: I see, I guess I'm getting the idea wrong, you mean my ForMerchantAnnotation annotation is supposed to be placed at the controller class, instead of method, is that correct? Does it means after putting the `within` clause I'd be able to continue putting it on method? Or do I have to place it at Controller?

Comment: No , `@annotation` PCD is for methods that being executed is annotated with a particular annotation . Your condition had `args()` which means the method SHOULD have an argument of type `HttpServletRequest` . The answer I provided will work without `within()` as well , but in that case the framework will have a global scope to check for matching methods. With `within()` the packages within which the advice needs to be applied is limited , hence performant. Also you dont have to move the annotation to class level in both cases , as the pointcut designator we use is `@annotation`

Comment: Ahh yes I get what you mean now, the problem lies at my args() parameter, because I was expecting a `HttpServletRequest` at my before() method, removing it works, and adding within is meant to control the scope, thank you!